# How to convert my code from C# to Python?

Tags: c#, .net, python, ironpython

How can I convert this code from C# to Python to be run on IronPython?

I don't have any experience with Python.

```
using System;
using Baz;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
        Portal foo = new Portal("Foo"); 
        Agent bar = new Agent("Bar");

        foo.Connect("127.0.0.1", 1234); 
        foo.Add(bar);

        bar.Ready += new Agent.ReadyHandler(bar_Ready);               
    }

    static void bar_Ready(object sender, string msg)
    {    
       Console.WriteLine(msg.body);  
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instantiation doesn't require a type definition. Methods called the same, assign delegates directly. The previous answer is absolutely right, you'll need a **lot** more context in order to "convert" a C# application to Python; it's more than just syntax.

```
foo = Portal("Foo")

bar = Agent("bar")

foo.Connect("ip", 1234)

foo.Add(bar)

bar.Ready = bar_Ready

def bar_Ready(sender, msg):

    print msg.body
```

Comment: This is right, except that the event hook line should be 'bar.Ready += bar_Ready' if you assume that the Portal and Agent classes are still implemented in C#.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would suit you best if you take a look at the following links:

http://www.learningpython.com/2006/10/02/ironpython-hello-world-tutorial/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300810.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Or if you're feeling really lazy,  there's a [C# to Python converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-python/) on developer fusion!

Answer (score -1):

In case someone else has this question SharpDevelop has a conversion utility to convert between C# and IronPython, VB.NET or Boo
http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2009/05/11/ConvertingCSharpVBNetCodeToIronPython.aspx